# CSS: table layout to match page width

Tags: html, css, layout, html-table

I would like to print 500 words in a table layout, so words organize in columns like this:

```
abc      alpha  beta        gammalong
a        beta   zu          delta
epsilon  zu     deltagamma  alpha
```

If I use TABLE tag I have to predifine row length (in words), so some pepole would see not all page filled with words and others would have to scroll.

How do I make such a layout, which fits page width exactly, automatically choosing number of words it could put in a row to match page width?

Comment: Could you elaborate how this can help me in solving the task? On one screen size my table will result in, lets say, 100 rows and 4 columns and on another - 40 rows and 10 columns...

Comment: i think you want to design responsive page,so maybe bootstap help you,please search it in google :)

Comment: @DenisKulagin assign 25% of width to each column

Answer (score 1):

if you use % for your tags size,it will be ok.

Answer (score 0):

you can use `<div> tags` and css classes such as `display:table and display:table-row and table-cell` to put them in right place.

Answer (score 0):

Put them all in divs that are set with "float: left" and give them all the same width. for example:

(Put the styles in a CSS file, they're inline just for the example)

```
<div style="position: relative; float: left; margin-right: 10px; width: 150px; height: 25px;">abc</div>
<div style="position: relative; float: left; margin-right: 10px; width: 150px; height: 25px;">alpha</div>
<div style="position: relative; float: left; margin-right: 10px; width: 150px; height: 25px;">beta</div>
<div style="position: relative; float: left; margin-right: 10px; width: 150px; height: 25px;">gammalong</div>
```

They will continue to stretch out to the right until they hit the width of the parent node (possibly `document.body` if they're not in another element).

Comment: It'll do, but it also may eat space, if none of the words match predefined length.

Comment: @DenisKulagin it does exactly what you want to do, just give the DIVs a set width and height and the words will wrap inside them. This is exactly what would happen with table cells as well.